# Upgrading to PHP 5.5 MAMP PRO

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm not a programming expert but I am trying to get more into Dynamic Website design using PHP. There's a hashing library on the new PHP version 5.5 that I want to use on a project but right now I'm running PHP 5.4. I use MAMP PRO V 2.1.4 and after looking online and on their site I couldn't find anything with step-by-step instructions on how to update the current PHP version I'm using. I was able to download a v5.5 folder from their site that they say is compatible with the version of MAMP I own. Here's what I've tried so far...

Ok so I looked at the php info page.

[image]

It looks like I need to add the new php version folder to my MAMP/bin/php folder and I did that. But it still doesn't show up as a selection on MAMP Pro.

[image]

So I read somewhere that MAMP Pro V 2.x only gives you two options for PHP and that I should rename the other folders in the PHP file.

[image]

I feel like I'm missing a important step. Any advice would be great! If you have any questions please ask. Hopefully I can figure this out and this post will help future non-program savvy web designers too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the esasiest way is to copy your  PHP files somewhere else and then use [Appdelete](http://www.reggieashworth.com/appdelete) or similar, and delete the MAMP folder in your applications folder and re-install.  I had to do this after a Yosemite install broke the older version of MAMP.  Why keep the older versions?

Answer (score 0):

I agree reinstall is very safe. u dont need to take a copy of old MAMP. the new install does it on its own. just feel free to downlod new MAMP and click install.
only care u need to take is this

**Edit httpd.conf and open up line to include vhosts.conf and copy old vhosts.conf from old MAMP folder.**